# pthread_create skips or repeats

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

pthread_create function gets skipped or sometimes called twice.
The question I am solving is:

Given a global array that contains number from 1 to 100. You are required to make 10 threads and each thread must find the sum of square of 10 numbers.

Thread 1 must calculate from 1 to 10

Thread 2 must calculate from 11 to 20

...so on.

Each thread must return its individual sum to a global variable sum initialized with zero.

My try:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<semaphore.h>

int arr[100];

sem_t s;

int sum=0;

void *calculate(void *i){
    sem_wait(&s);
    int j=(*((int*)i));
    int k;
    printf("j: %d\n",j);
    int temp=0;
    for(k=j*10;k<(j*10)+10;k++){
        temp=temp+(arr[k]*arr[k]);
    }
    sum+=temp;

    printf("sum: %d j: %d\n\n",sum,j);

    sem_post(&s);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    sem_init(&s,0,1);
    pthread_t threads_array[10];
    int i=0;
    int *k=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        arr[i]=i+1;
    }

    int temp=0,temp_i;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        (*k)=i;
        printf("k: %d\n",(*k));
        pthread_create(&(threads_array[i]),NULL,calculate,(void*)k);
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
       pthread_join(threads_array[i],NULL);
    }

    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I have used semaphores. So that only one thread access the global resource at a time.

The output I am getting is:

[Output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l97Tg.png)

My question is why is it repeating some values and skipping some? I am not using pthread_create correctly?

I have also tried using a new value of k each time:

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    int *k=&i;
    printf("k: %d\n",(*k));
    pthread_create(&(threads_array[i]),NULL,calculate,(void*)k);

}
```

Comment: Instead of linking an image, it would be better to paste the output within the post itself, much like you've done with your code.

Comment: `k` is shared among your threads... Use some thread local storage or an array of ten variables... Don't take the semaphore will computing the local sum, just use it to protect the `sum+=` section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code passes the same address of `k` to each thread, but *it changes the value in that memory*:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    (*k)=i;
    printf("k: %d\n",(*k));
    pthread_create(&(threads_array[i]),NULL,calculate,(void*)k);
}
```

By the time this code runs

```
void *calculate(void *i){
    sem_wait(&s);
    int j=(*((int*)i));
        .
        .
        .
```

the value has likely changed because the main thread changed it.

This would be better, as it passes the *value* of `i`, but it depends on the existence of `intptr_t` and platform-specific behavior allowing the transformation back to `int`, so it's not strictly compliant C code:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    pthread_create(&(threads_array[i]),NULL,calculate,(void*)(intptr_t)i);
}
```

and

```
void *calculate(void *i){
    sem_wait(&s);
    int j= (intptr_t)i;
```

That passes the *value* of `i` as a `void *` pointer value.

But if `intptr_t` exists, this is better:

```
intptr_t i;
    .
    .
    .
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    pthread_create(&(threads_array[i]),NULL,calculate,(void*)i);
}
```

and

```
void *calculate(void *i){
    sem_wait(&s);
    intptr_t j= (intptr_t)i;
```

Realistically, there aren't many platforms out there any more that approach won't work on.

Alternatively, in strictly conforming C, to pass the address of an actual `int` value, you need a separate `int` for each thread that's guaranteed to exist when the thread is running:

```
// this is a local variable, but since it's in the same scope as
// both pthread_create() and pthread_join(), it will still exist
// for the entire lifetime of each thread created
int threadnum[10];

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    threadnum[i]=i;
    pthread_create(&(threads_array[i]),NULL,calculate,(void*)&(threadnum[i]));
}
```

and

```
void *calculate(void *i){
    sem_wait(&s);
    int j=(*((int*)i));
```

Comment: I also tried passing new value of k every time the loop runs. Please check the edit

Comment: @JasmineKaur You're passing the same address to each thread.  Then you modify the value in that memory, but you have no control over which thread runs first, and you don't know *when* they will run.  The threads might not even start until your main thread is blocked in the `pthread_join()` loop.  Your edit doesn't really help as you're passing the address of a local loop variable that's likely out of scope by the time the thread tries to dereference the pointer.

Comment: Awesome. That array idea seems so logical, I learnt my mistake